# How to listen to android MediaPlayer position change event

Tags: android, position, android-mediaplayer, media-player

While playing a video nor audio via the Android [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer)
how can one receive every 10 ms (or any specific delay) the current player position, while its playing (and stop receiving while its not playing)

I prefer not to use handler that post delay itself.
It needs to be cancelable.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use a `Timer`:**

```
//member field 
Timer timer;


//somewhere in your code:

timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {

if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

//get current position of playback because player is playing

int position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
Log.d("POSITION" , String.valueOf(position));

}else{

//player is not playing do nothing.......

}


}

},0,1000); //1000 is a long value in milliseconds (in this case it runs every 1 second)
```

When you want to cancel the timer:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Comment: thanks. would it be any different if I use post delay with handler that calls it self with post delay and use handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) to stop it? Is using timer is better option?

Comment: For your case its fine.